# Can I build Android apps using C# in visual studio

Tags: java, c#, android, visual-studio

Can I build Android apps using C# in visual studio ?

If there is a way of doing that, what is the better using java or C# ?

Comment: Actually your question is too broad, and it is even "two broad questions in one". Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask a good question at StackOverflow...

Comment: I don't know of any way to do exactly that but there are other solutions out there like phonegap among a lot of others, which let you program in something else, then convert it to the platform's native code. Maybe someone made something like that for C#, though I don't know if microsoft would let that happen because of the windows phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion i always have to fight with myself and about the languages. C# and java are two totally different languages with similar syntax. The question you should really be asking is "what do  i want to do". then debate over the language. I would say stick to java for android applications. However if you want to use c#. You cannot use Visual studios for this. However there is an alternative to visual studios and its [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/?_bt=44014802708&_bk=xamarin&_bm=e&gclid=CPip0JzrpMMCFezHtAod9jcAIg). I haven't personally used it though i know people who have and its very good.

But yes, Figure out what you want to do and which language would be best doing that.

Comment: I struggle with this too. Too many options! I split it in to "Simple UI" apps that don't require animations etc. These I am happy to do with Cordova/PhoneGap and use the PhoneGap build service - it is marvelous :)  The other is "UI heavy apps" I dont really write animation heavy apps or build games, but I would go native for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. You can use Cordova/PhoneGap with Visual Studio to build apps. 
[Cordova for VS](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/cordova-vs.aspx)

This does not use C# (apart from your back end services, which can be anything really). I use this with Angular.js and [ngcordova] to build apps and it works nicely.

You can have a "more C#" experience using Xamarin, there is a simple free version but a really rich experience requires a license purchase. Explore it further at [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/)